# SQL Server 2012 scope_identity advise

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, identity-column, scope-identity

I created a stored procedure in SQL Server 2012 and I have used `scope_identity` to get identity column's value but in my case I do not know is this correct or not please help

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Add_Translation
    @english nvarchar(70),
    @kurdish nvarchar(70),
    @english_category int,
    @kurdish_category int,
    @result int out
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    if @english is not null and @kurdish is not null and @english_category is not null and @kurdish_category is not null
    begin
        insert into english_table values(@english, @english_category);

        declare @identityEnglish int;
        set @identityEnglish = SCOPE_IDENTITY();

        insert into kurdish_table values(@kurdish, @kurdish_category);
        declare @identityKurdish int;
        set @identityKurdish = SCOPE_IDENTITY();

        insert into transactions values(@identityEnglish, @identityKurdish);
        set @result = 1;
    end
    else
    begin
        set @result = 0;
    end
END
```

My question is that will the variable `@identityEnglish` get last identity value of `english_table` and variable `@identityKurdish` get last identity value of `kurdish_table`

thank you..

Comment: Yes, that's correct.  Is it not working?

Comment: thank you for helping it is working but asked because both table identity column start with 1 and increment by 1 and I thought that scope_identity will remain same for the first transaction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the inserts succeed then `scope_identity()` works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "Output" clause on DML operations.

[Click here](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/10/01/sql-server-2005-output-clause-example-and-explanation-with-insert-update-delete/)